# Range indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Tags: python

```
tp_count = len(time_points) 
xtick_label_stepsize = tp_count / 15 
if xtick_label_stepsize == 0: 
    xtick_label_stepsize = 1 
    self.x_data = range(tp_count) 
    self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count, xtick_label_stepsize)
    self.xtick_labels = [self.x_data[i] for i in self.xticks]
```

**Error: range indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64**

Comment: Pease [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992015/range-indices-must-be-integers-or-slices-not-numpy-float64#) and add some text describing what you are trying to do.

Comment: The problem is `self.x_data[i]`, because `i` is a float. You can use `np.arange(..., dtype=int)` to have integers as `self.xticks`. But I suspect that you really want to think about your problem again, because it does not look like the ticks should always be integers. But you can only index your data with integers (because `self.x_data[1.5]` would not make any sense).

Comment: I have used np.arrange(...,dtype=int) but its showing value as "0" --> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

Answer (score 0):

Range will support integers, try converting it

```
self.x_data = range(int(tp_count))
```

Comment: That's not indexing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the step variable can be a non integer value, because you use a single `/`. For `np.arange` to produce an integer array, all of its input parameters must be integers, or you must explicitely ask an integer dtype.

So here are 2 possible fixes:

1. make `xtick_label_stepsize` integer:

   ```
    xtick_label_stepsize = tp_count // 15
    ...
   ```
2. force an integer dtype:

   ```
    ...
    self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count, xtick_label_stepsize, dtype='int32')
    ...
   ```

---

After a second look, the former will be more robust, since you manually handle the case where the step reaches 0. For the second way, you must handle it anyway for example with:

```
if self.xticks[-1] == 0:
    self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count)
```

But if it often occurs, if it more resource consuming that the first way.

Comment: Its worked but self.xticks values are showing "0"  --> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

Comment: self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count, xtick_label_stepsize)

        if self.xticks[-1] == 0:
            self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count)

        self.xtick_labels = [self.x_data[i] for i in self.xticks]

Comment: if self.xticks[-1] == 0:
            self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count)

        self.xtick_labels = [self.x_data[i] for i in self.xticks]

Comment: It now looks like a different problem. Without knowing self.x_data, tp_count, and self.xticks at the moment of the error I cannot help here.

Comment: tp_count = 1 , xtick_label_stepsize = 0.06666666666666667 , time_points = "b'11:40:24" , self.xdata = {range(0,1) , start = 0, step = 1 and stop = 1} , self.xticks = [0:15] --> [0.0, 0.06666666666666667, 0.13333333333333333, 0.2, 0.26666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.4, 0.4666666666666667, 0.5333333333333333, 0.6, 0.6666666666666666, 0.7333333333333333, 0.8, 0.8666666666666667, ...]

Comment: @nallapayan420 You did not forget `dtypes=int32` in first `arange` call, did you? Anyway I strongly advise you to use first way because it looks smoother and simpler.

Comment: I have applied your point : self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count, xtick_label_stepsize,dtype='int32') but self.xticks = [0:15] --> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...] as zero

Comment: I have just advised you to use the **first** way. Why do you still try to use the second one that you do not understand?

Comment: First Method only, I have used "xtick_label_stepsize = tp_count // 15 (value is 0)" and "self.xticks = np.arange(0, tp_count, xtick_label_stepsize, dtype='int32')" --> showing error as "division by zero"

Comment: In shown code, second instruction is `if xtick_label_stepsize == 0: 
    xtick_label_stepsize = 1` ... Did you understand your own code? Well I apologize for being rude, but you are supposed to do some efforts by yourself...

Comment: I have used which you shared, now its working fine but self.xticks and self.xtick_lables are showing value as zero so it will impact to create the graph. please help me with that.

Comment: @nallapayan420: what can you expect if `tp_count` is 1 and `self.xdata` (`range(0,1)`) contains one single value which is 0?

Comment: I thought cpu_usage += "\n" + part is showing the error as "can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str". please help on this.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand what you are actually trying to achieve. And I see no `cpu_usage` in shown code. I really tried to help you, and I apologize if I was rude. But in the first place I should have insisted that you write a better question with a [mcve] and some context. Now I can only advise you to delete that question, build a [mcve] with enough code and data so that others can reproduce and then ask a new (and better) question. And remember to read (again?) [ask] to have  more hints on how to write a good question.

Comment: Please check this link for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013528/we-can-not-concatenate-string-not-bytes-to-string

Comment: @nallapayan420: Hint just google for your error message. The first link (from SO...) contains the reason for the error and some solutions or workarounds.